# Change value of div with while

Tags: php, html, css

I need put this divs in this order:

```
<div class="col-md-9"> 1 box </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> 2 box </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> 3 box </div>
<div class="col-md-9"> 4 box </div>
<div class="col-md-9"> 5 box </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> 6 box </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> 7 box </div>
<div class="col-md-9"> 8 box </div>
```

An continue in this order. I try make it with a while but I can't find an algoritm that put me the divs in this order.

This is the code that I try but don't work:

```
$count = 0;

    while($items = mysql_fetch_array($consult))
    {
        if($count % 2 == 0)
        {
            echo '<div class"col-md-9"> '.$items['title'].' </div>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div class="col-md-3"> '.$items['title'].' </div>';
        }
    }
```

This show me:

```
<div class="col-md-9"> value </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> value </div>
<div class="col-md-9"> value </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> value </div>
```

Any idea?

Regards

Comment: What does that mean? ... Posting an image of the expected result would help

Comment: In order by what?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to order divs using php?

Comment: @Mohammad yes, i need put this divs with a while in this order: First col-md-9, and next col-md-3, then continue: 3-9-9-3-3-9-9-3-3-9...

Comment: @LemuelBotha the col-md of the divs. See that the col-md's have this order: 9-3-3-9-9-3-3-9

Comment: @LGSon I can't post an image because my boss give me this problem and I don't know how to make a while that make this. I try with counts but don't have success

Comment: How many divs do you need?

Comment: Are you dynamically creating the divs? If so, post how you're creating them.

Comment: @LemuelBotha infinite, the number are defined by the user who visit the webpage.

Comment: Where is this user defined number set or how does the user add a div?

Comment: @LemuelBotha check the main post, I add an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st: **don't use MYSQL_* commands, they are deprecated and unsafe!**

2nd: This should do. *Notice: I did not test it, just wrote a quick example*:

```
$count = 1;
$md = 9;

while ($items = mysql_fetch_array($consult)) {
    $count++;
    echo '<div class="col-md-' . $md . '"> ' . $items['title'] . ' </div>';

    if ($count > 1) {
        $md = $md == 3 ? 9 : 3;
        $count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"don't use MYSQL_\* commands, they are deprecated and **unsafe**"*  - Agreed, yet only if user input is involved and it doesn't seem to be the case here. They're just displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Make sure you receive the values in order by adding "ORDER BY" to your sql statement.
2. First retrieve all values from the SQL in an arrray, then sort the array (e.g. `asort`) and then run your loop to produce the DIVs

If you can I would recommend option 1. Its usually faster to use your the DB for sorting.